# how to get content in kindeditor through js

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am using kindeditor to store data and passing that value in js .. it is working properly but while editing i am not getting my content to update....

```
<script>

    var editor;
    KindEditor.ready(function(K) {      
        editor = K.create('textarea[name="eventContent"]', {
            allowFileManager : true,
            langType : 'en'
        });

        K('input[name=getHtml]').click(function(e) {
            alert(editor.html());
        });

        //here
        var eventContent = (editor.html());
    });
</script>

var eventContent = (editor.html());
```